# How to keep a user signed-in using a token from a different app in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, session

I just have one “minor” question. I’m trying to build two Rails apps:

1. That accepts and returns JSONs (server side) and
2. That renders views and such for the user (client side)

I've managed to build the User registration part. But I’m having issues in the whole `Sessions` part of the application. I’m not sure how to keep the user signed in across the apps OR how to even use the `token`, that was sent from the server side using Devise or any other engine like that.

So, what I'm trying to do is this:

- The user fills in a sign in form on the client side
- That form sends JSON data to the server side
- Which (I assume) should send back a JSON consisting of the user's data and some sort of token

How can I use that `token` to keep the user signed in on the client side? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can store the access_token returned by the server app as session in your client app,
and use this for maintaining session at your client application.

Also you can get the user details and store the user id in the session for your client application.

> session[:user_id] =
>
> session[:access_token] =

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I believe I can successfully set the session[:user_id] by using the JSON I get from my server side after signing in. After that, I must somehow set the current_user variable which I need in my views. This is where I'm lost :(

Comment: All basic examples I saw about current user make a call to the database, as in: current_user ||= User.find_by(session[:user_id]). However, that's not very RESTful. So I need to make another API call to my server side, and retrieve user data from the database, something like this: `resp = HTTParty.post url, :body => { "id" => session[:user_id]}; current_user ||= JSON.parse(resp.body)`. But the current_user variable is always `nil`

Comment: Ok, you can get the access token and the user details in the same call to be returned when your signing up. Also how are you creating the token and is this token only valid till the user session is maintained?

Comment: I haven't actually implemented the `token` part yet. I was going for a more basic (and unsecure) session management using just `session[:user_id]`. Do I absolutely need a special token like the one Devise provides in order to maintain a session?